# Função no evento mouseover não funciona no Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

Eu possuo uma função em JavaScript que é ativada através do evento `onmouseover` em um tabela com registros, o campo muda de cor quando passo o mouse, até ai tudo bem o problema é que ela só funciona nos navegadores IE e google chrome, já no Mozilla ela não funciona o que eu faço?

```
onmouseover="mOvr(this,'#A8A8A8');"

function mOvr(src, clrOver) {
    if (!src.contains(event.fromElement)) {
        src.bgColor = clrOver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual versão especifica do firefox? no console de erros aparece alguma mensagem?

Comment: versão 35.0.1 e aparece ReferenceError: event is not defined scripts.js:8:8 no console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isto é um bug antigo conhecido. O problema é que o Firefox não usa `event.fromElement` (nem `.toElement`) e os outros não usam `event.relatedTarget` que o Firefox usa... assim tens de detectar essa feature e adaptar o código e comparar se o `event.relatedTarget` e o `event.target` são o mesmo. Podes dar uma olhada ao [código fonte do jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/10399ddcf8a239acc27bdec9231b996b178224d3/test/data/jquery-1.9.1.js#L3210-L3224).

Podias usar uma função deste tipo para corrigir isso:

```
function fix(event) {
    if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
        event.fromElement = event.relatedTarget;
    }
    if (event.type == 'mouseleave') {
        event.toElement = event.relatedTarget;
    }
}
```

Mas vendo que tens `!src.contains(event.fromElement)` presumo que queiras esse comportamento só no `mouseenter`do `src` (ou seja `src` não contém o elemento de onde o mouse veio), então acho melhor usares mesmo o `onmouseenter=""` e se quiseres repôr, usando o `onmouseleave`. Algo como isto: http://jsfiddle.net/far4q1ja/

Porém o mais sensato seria usar CSS para efeitos de mousehover... se puderes vai por essa via e dá classes de CSS a esses elementos para poderes escrever regras no ficheiro CSS.

**PS:** O erro que referiste `ReferenceError: event is not defined scripts.js:8:8` é porque estás a usar `event` dentro da função sem teres passado um argumento com esse nome. Assim tens de defenir a função com esse parâmetro:

```
function mOvr(src, clrOver, event) {
```

e depois no inline usar `onmouseover="mOvr(this,'#A8A8A8', event);"`.

Comment: Sergio a sua resposta em  http://jsfiddle.net/far4q1ja/ deu certo e coloquei o event agora foi.

Comment: Como posso dizer que a sua resposta é a correta?

Comment: @jp_almeida dá uma olhada aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz assim deu certo, só que não tem como passar no parâmetro do evento.

```
function mOvr(obj,color) {
    obj.style.backgroundColor = "#A8A8A8";
}
```